# Why short links are introduced?

Tags: url, hyperlink

I see in many sites the use of `short links` like this:

`http://www.chipbennett.net/2011/04/28/2011-nfl-draft-colts-round-1/`

to this

`http://bit.ly/mxytw8`

but I wonder to know why they've been used!

The only thing I could imagine is to hide the original link or to gain data weight in a database?

Comment: they're more cooler and easy to read (when customized) than the original link :o)

Answer (score 3):

Simply because services like Twitter are limited in the message size. Or to make it easier to type in the address instead of copy/pasting. Could also be misused by spammers or phishing attacks to hide the real address. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening

Answer (score 2):

The user may be doing it to take advantage of [link tracking](http://bit.ly/a/help#i_3_0) provided by bitly.

> Every bitly link has an info page, which reveals the number of related clicks and other relevant data. You can get to the info page in a few different ways.

Answer (score 1):

They're mostly used with Twitter (which has a very short message size) and historically for plain text email where mail readers would line-wrap long URLs in the middle.